# OpenShift Online API responds with single white space and HTTP 406 "not acceptable" to any request

Tags: openshift

According to the [OpenShift docs](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/REST_API_Guide/chap-API_Entry_Point.html), the following should return a result:

`curl -X GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api`

However, any call to the API actually just returns a single whitespace - including those called with username & password.

I've confirmed the issue from several different machines accross the globe.

**What might be the reason?**

Answer (score 0):

Inspired by [a similar question regarding Twitter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4758966/twitter-api-406-not-acceptable-response), I added `.json` at the end of the URL and it worked:

`curl -X GET https://openshift.redhat.com/broker/rest/api.json`

It's kind of disappointing that RedHat never replied to any inquiry regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is logged here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1324208

You can add yourself to the "cc" if you would like to be notified as the fix gets rolled out to production.

FYI, asking for help on a public forum and giving it only 4 hours for a response from the company seems a bit much.  In the future it may be worth it for you to either check for open bugs, or to [ask the company directly](https://developers.openshift.com/contact) instead.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, Corey. I was not referring to a response here on SO. About six weeks ago, we sent emails to the main customerservice address and to the -de variant. Both reman unanswered. In an occasional customer satisfaction survey we pointed that out. Still no response. Maybe we were ignored because we're on a Bronce plan (paid, but without support). For **actual bugs**, I'd expect a response regardless. We're also struggling with http://stackoverflow.com/q/36781860/569825 which has not yet received any answer by the community, simply because our code looks as if **it should work**.